# ffmpeg - Is it possibe to retain real timecodes using -copyts?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, webm

It's is a simple task.
I want to make a converted clip of a video using `-copyts` to have it's real timecodes. For example, the converted clip of this command:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -ss 57:41.76 -i input.mp4 -copyts -fs 4085Ki -vf scale=1280:-1 -c:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 1000K -maxrate:v 1600K -bufsize 800Ki -threads 4 -quality good -cpu-used 5 -c:a libvorbis -b:a 64Ki -maxrate:a 128Ki input.webm
```

Has a 31 seconds duration, but:

```
frame=  938 fps=7.7 q=0.0 Lsize=    4089kB time=00:58:13.15 bitrate=   9.6kbits/s speed=28.8x
```

Says that it has 58:13.15 minutes.

I can achieve the normal duration by removing `-copyts` from the command code but the whole reason I'm using `-copyts` is to avoid having to calculate the next segments every time, since I can just set `-ss` to 58:13.15 and get going.

For the question, is there anyway to modify the converted files duration **without** re-converting it? Like modifying metadata?

I'm on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

I just had to `-c copy`. Had forgotten about it:

Put all your new clips in a new folder (webm as a suggestion) and inside that folder, create another folder named `new` and do this

`ffmpeg -i input.webm -c copy new\output.webm`

For an automated process do this:

`for %i in ("*.webm") do ffmpeg -i %i -c copy new\%~ni.webm`

This will repeat the `-c copy` command to all the clips you converted.